Getting value of "Editable" checkbox in layer fields widget settings with Python?
I have been trying to find a way to check the editability state of fields within a layer in QGIS 3.34 with no luck. I've tried using QgsVectorLayerUtils calls of fieldIsReadOnly, fieldIsEditable, and fieldEditabilityDependsOnFeature, and none of these seem to check against that checkbox. For clarification, the checkbox I am referring to is the one in the general settings for a field inside the Layer->Fields properties UI. The code I have been using is below; I am trying to define field_is_editable based on the state of that checkbox and make a read-only line in the form generated if that checkbox is checked. I've also tried using QgsEditorWidgetSetup.config() to see if I could find a setting in that which could be used, but that only seemed to return whether the widget was multi-line or HTML.
Is there a way to programmatically check the state of the "Editable" checkbox?
def load_layer_form(self):
    # Clear the current form
    for i in reversed(range(self.form_layout.count())):
        widget = self.form_layout.itemAt(i).widget()
        if widget is not None:
            widget.deleteLater()

    # Get the selected layer
    layer_name = self.layer_combo.currentText()
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    # Create form widgets for each field
    for field in layer.fields():
        field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName(field.name())
        widget_setup = layer.editorWidgetSetup(field_index)
        widget_type = widget_setup.type()

        #field_is_editable = QgsVectorLayerUtils.fieldIsEditable(layer, field_index)

        if field_is_editable:
            widget = self.create_widget(widget_type, widget_setup.config(), field)
            if widget:
                self.form_layout.addRow(field.name(), widget)
        else:
            # Add a non-editable label instead
            label = QLabel(f"{field.name()}: Not-Editable")
            self.form_layout.addRow(label)


Those methods of QgsVectorLayerUtils also take into account the edit state of the layer, as well as the provider capabilities etc.
You can see the logic used in the source code for the QgsVectorLayerUtils.fieldIsReadOnly(), fieldIsEditable() and _fieldIsEditable() methods.
If you just want to explicitly check the state of the Editable checkbox, use the following:
read_only = layer.editFormConfig().readOnly(field_index)

Link to docs. Note that:

This returns true if the field is manually set to read only or if the
field does not support editing like joins or virtual fields.

P.s. If you know that the edit state of the layer is the only blocker, you could wrap the other tests in a with edit(layer): call.
E.g.
with edit(layer):
    read_only = QgsVectorLayerUtils.fieldIsReadOnly(layer, field_index)

